# git: error: SDK "macosx" cannot be located

Tags: macos, git, osx-yosemite

Just updated my machine to Yosemite. I'm getting this error from Git now:

```
git: error: SDK "macosx" cannot be located
```

I'm able to run `git status` with no issue, but anything like `git add` seems to work, but then throws this error. Command Line Tools are installed, I tried reinstalling Git.

Comment: You may check if sdk path is known to system: `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path`

Comment: does not appear to be, I get a similar error, followed by `xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'macosx'`. What does it mean?

Comment: What about `xcode-select --print-path`? It should point to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: it points to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: Try `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`. Adjust the path if you have Xcode installed elsewhere.

Comment: `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'`. I'm not actually using Xcode, just the command line tools because Git requires them. Should I just reinstall the cmd line tools?

Comment: Yes, reinstall CLT, maybe you don't have latest version.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not sure exactly what, but something got out of whack during the upgrade. Uninstall CommandLineTools by typing `sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` then reinstall. I just typed some git command like: `git status` and let the OS prompt me to install the CommandLineTools. Everything is happy now.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the `git: error: SDK "macosx" cannot be located` which lead me to this page.

I was also getting the message like "too many files open" and "could not fork".

Closing Spotify solved by problem. I did not reinstall Git.