# INTELLIJ IDEA ERROR: "Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git Probably the path to Git executable is not valid. Fix it." How to Fix it?

Tags: java, git, macos, intellij-idea, macos-mojave

I updated my mac to macOS Mojave version 10.14, I already had Xcode installed in the previous OS version and now while I run intelliJ this error is thrown:-

> Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git Probably the path to Git executable is
>   not valid. Fix it

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bemor.png)

Comment: Try to run it from console (with full path). What output do you have?

Comment: How to run it from console ?

Comment: *"How to run it from console ?"*  - Type "git --version"!   Then "which git".  But my bet is that you don't have a free-standing "git" installation.  So the solution would be to install git!

Comment: @StephenC it will be better to type `/usr/bin/git` because it is what Idea try to run.

Comment: Except that "/usr/bin/git" is not correct.  See the error message!

Comment: I don't have experience with Mac, but google said you can try this https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line

Comment: when i typed git it throwed this error

git: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
git: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'

Comment: @StephenC I think that's default path for git. We need to find out why it is error. There is several option here: file don't exist, file is not accessible, file is corrupted. Running it in console can give us a clue about what is actually happened.

Comment: You could try this .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388636/git-error-sdk-macosx-cannot-be-located

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665394/git-error-unable-to-read-sdk-settings-for-macosx-sdk.  In fact, my guess is that your Q is a dup of this one.  Basically, it says you need to **update** your XCode installation.

Comment: I encountered this issue as well with IntelliJ @StephenC but I did not get the error described in that question from terminal, only from IntelliJ. I posted the steps which worked to resolve the issue IntelliJ was having.

Answer (score 12):

To solve this problem you need to install xcode developer tools.

Run this command, the problem will be fixed:

`xcode-select --install`

I had the same problem after upgrade and this solved it.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same error on mac after updating the OS to Ventura. Tried the above solutions which did not solve the error,

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates

What worked: System Settings --> Privacy and Security --> Developer Tools 
Toggle the button next to Terminal

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDMyD.png)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Remember to also restart your IDE afterwards (duh).

Comment: I don't even know whom to blame here. Was Apple supposed to enable the Terminal? Users could have wasted hours troubleshooting it if not this post.

Answer (score 4):

I performed the following steps to solve this problem:

1. Run `sudo xcode-select --switch  /Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (this step may be optional)
2. Open **App Store**
3. Update **xcode**
4. *Wait for update to complete before continuing with next steps*
5. Run `sudo xcodebuild -license`
6. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> key to view agreement (to page down the agreement hold <kbd>space</kbd> or press it multiple times)
7. Once at the end of the agreement if you agree type `agree` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
8. Close and re-open IntelliJ and GIT should work again.

I hope this helps others!

Comment: when running `sudo xcodebuild -license` i get this error message: `xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`

Comment: You have xcode installed? Could the active dev directory be incorrect?